# Fitting model to Wood's lactation curve

Tags: model, function

I'm trying to determine how I can estimate the following model:

$y = at^bexp(ct)$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are estimate from a set of data.

But I can't figure out how to derive the formula into something more manageable.

I'm trying to fit the model but I'm unsure how to estimate it with the following data:

```
Yield<-c(0.31, 0.39, 0.50, 0.58, 0.59, 0.64, 0.68, 0.66, 
         0.67, 0.70, 0.72, 0.68, 0.65, 0.64, 0.57, 0.48, 
         0.46, 0.45, 0.31, 0.33, 0.36, 0.30, 0.26, 0.34, 
         0.29, 0.31, 0.29, 0.20, 0.15, 0.18, 0.11, 0.07,
         0.06, 0.01, 0.01)
Week<-1:35
```

Comment: Is this all your data are do you have more data for other animals?  It looks like you only have data here for one animal.  Is this right?

Comment: Take a look at the `lactcurves` package in R.  It will fit wood's model, but note that the package implements $y = at^bexp(-ct)$ (note the negative sign):  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lactcurves/lactcurves.pdf

Answer (score 1):

How about [nonlinear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares)? This is what the package `lactcurves` already mentioned uses under the hood. In R you can feed the formula directly in to the `nls()` function without modification - provided it has some reasonable start points.

```
# Fit model using nls
fit <- nls(Yield ~ a * Week^b * exp(c*Week), 
           data = data.frame(Yield, Week),
           start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = .01))

# Plot curve against data
plot(Week, Yield)
lines(Week, predict(fit), col = "blue")
```

[image: nls curve]